# JPA (EclipseLink) list order

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm having some problem with keeping the order of a list during persistence when using EclipseLink. Am I missing some setting in EclipseLink, or forgetting to use some annotation?

I have two classes that looks somewhat like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sequence")
public final class Sequence {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "sequence")
    private List<Run> runs;

    // Other fields
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "run")
public final class Run {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "seq_id", nullable = false)
    private Sequence sequence;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String comment;

    // Other fields
    // ...
}
```

Now, I expect that when I add instances of the latter class to the former, the order in the list will be kept when persiting:

```
Run a = new Run();
a.setComment("a");

Run b = new Run();
b.setComment("b");

List<Run> runs = new LinkedList<Run>();
runs.add(a);
runs.add(b);

Sequence seq = new Sequence();
seq.setRuns(runs);

persist(seq); // order in database should be "a", then "b"
```

However, when I check the database, it's not always so that the instance **a** gets a lower identifier than **b**; it seems to behave as if the list is just a bucket.

How do I keep the order of the list when using persistence? If the instance **a** is added before **b**, I want to keep the order in the database as the entries are results of a sequential execution of tests and the order must be perserved.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you don't specify any ordering `@OrderBy` or `@OrderColumn` then things are ordered based on the "id" of the element. Any JPA documentation would tell you this

Comment: I would assume that ids would be generated in the same order as the original list is, but I guess not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the order, you'll need an @OrderColumn annotation - by default, collection are saved with a "bag" semantic (no order involved). This can be added on a OneToMany or ManyToOne annotations.

Something like:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "sequence")
@OrderColumn
private List<Run> runs;
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html for the info.

Comment: This does not work for me. When I persist, I get the exception: Unkown column 'runs_ORDER' in 'field list'.

Comment: You'll need a specific column for the order in your DB (I don't think it can or should use the primary id for that).

Comment: I added an additional column to keep track of the list order. Feels a bit silly but it seems to be the only way. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this one? bit kludgy but no additional column is needed:

```
Sequence seq = new Sequence();
List<Run> runs = new LinkedList<Run>();
seq.setRuns(runs);

em.persist(seq);

Run a = new Run();
a.setSequence(seq);
a.setComment("a");
em.persist(a);
runs.add(a);
em.flush(); // this forces JPA provider to issue INSERT "a"

Run b = new Run();
b.setSequence(seq);
b.setComment("b");
em.persist(b);
runs.add(b);
em.flush(); // this forces JPA provider to issue INSERT "b"
```